# What does blue dot (circle) in Intellij IDEA mean?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, project-structure

I have read documentation on jetbrains and found no description what does the blue dot on webapp folder mean?

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow, your question is not about programming

Comment: @napi15 I think questions about IDEs are fine on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @napi15 ok, then please tell me what are IDEs for, if not programming

Comment: @napi15 you are so ingenious in finding the reason to avoid the point

Answer (score 3):

According to [JetBrains - Icon reference](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html), this symbol is the most similar to the **Package**.

The blue dot package icon is an *indicator* that the Web Facet has been configured correctly and is usually seen on the web source directory `src/main/webapp`.

My answer is based on personal experience and observation while working with IntelliJIdea. Unfortunately, I am unable to find any official documentation confirming the statement.

Answer (score 1):

The only information I could find related to Icon Reference guide (1) and the File Status Highlight guide (2). Additionally I found their list of new icons (3).

1. Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/symbols.html
2. Source: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/file-status-highlights.html
3. Source: https://blog.jetbrains.com/blog/2018/06/26/new-icons-in-intellij-platform-2018-2/

Hope this helps. Ill keep checking.

Comment: I have already seen these pages and found nothing about the dot :(

Comment: Could it be that the icon is for Package, but on the IntelliJ site it is not colored blue.
I agree with Nikolas, above.